# Modifying contents of a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, string, object, for-loop, dictionary

I have a list of "prof" objects called profList and then a dictionary (called collabDict) looks like this:

```
{17 : ['john', 'jim', 'fred'], 18 : ['tim', 'will', 'alex']}
```

I want to go through collabDict and change certain names from strings to the afore-mentioned "Prof" objects in profList, but only if a condition is met. The following code is my attempt but it does not change the values as intended

```
for a in profList :
    for key in collabDict :
        for b in collabDict.get(key,None) :
            if (some condition) :
                b = a
```

Any insight would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: can you show expected result?

Comment: "it does not change the values as intended" - What is the intended way?  Show sample input and output to show how it isn't as intended.

Comment: i want to change the output so that jim is no longer a string and now is an object. my code (as is) does not change the dictionary at all

Answer (score 1):

Having your dictionary:

```
>>> dct = {17 : ['john', 'jim', 'fred'], 18 : ['tim', 'will', 'alex']}
```

we define function, testing, if given name is in category of "prof" or not:

```
>>> isProf = lambda name: "i" in name
```

and using dict comprehension (available since Python 2.7) we change the names, if they are elegible
to being "Prof":

```
>>> {key: ["Prof" + name if isProf(name) else name for name in names] for key, names in dct.items()}
{17: ['john', 'Profjim', 'fred'], 18: ['Proftim', 'Profwill', 'alex']}
```

Disadvantage of this solution is, it rebuilds complete dictionary for each run. You shall know, if
this is acceptable or not.

Other solutions can change just the names which are to be changed this way:

```
isProf = lambda name: "i" in name
dct = {17 : ['john', 'jim', 'fred'], 18 : ['tim', 'will', 'alex']}
for num in dct:
    for i, name in enumerate(dct[num]):
        if isProf(name):
            dct[num][i] += "Prof"
print dct
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the new value by using the dict:

```
`collabDict[key] = a`
```

You are just setting `b = a`, that is not setting the value in `collabDict`

If you want a value in the list changed:

```
collabDict={17 : ['john', 'jim', 'fred'], 18 : ['tim', 'will', 'alex']}
ind = collabDict[17].index("john")
collabDict[17][ind]="b"
```

In your code something like:

```
for a in profList :
    for key in collabDict :
        for ind,b in enumerate(collabDict[key]) :
            if (some condition) :
                collabDict[key][ind] = a # change element at index to a
```

Comment: i dont want to set the value to a. I want the value to still be a list, except i want the string 'b' in the list to become the object 'a'

Comment: @user3798919, I added the code to change a single value